# forever running thread + updating UI in android

Tags: android, multithreading

Let's say I have a TextView and I want to update it's text with random numbers continuously, from the start of the application until it terminates.

What's the way to perform such a task? Does it have to be timed? (ie update it once in a second etc.) A statement with while(true) can't be used because there's only one UI thread in android and such a statement blocks it forever.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the quick and accurate answers. After seeing the answers and and thinking a little bit, I've come up with a tricky way to achieve this. Is there any downside of such a technique?

```
    TextView tv;
Handler myHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
    myHandler=new Handler();
    myHandler.post(new Nani());
}

    private class Nani implements Runnable{
    int i=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        myHandler.post(this);
        i++;
    }       
}
```

Simply, Runnable queues itself..

Comment: I would use something very similar. Can you even read the numbers calling it that fast? You could limit it to 10 times a second with `myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about what exactly you are doing such as when or why, you will want to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with `postAtTime()`.  [This part of the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) talks more about how to handle these things depending on what you need

Comment: @Sam sorry, I had several different things going on at the same time. I did reference the wrong link...my apologies and thank you.

Comment: postAtTime(Runnable r, long millis) just adds a runnable to the message queue at a specified time right? I didn't understand how it will help me to achieve desired behaviour.

Comment: @user1186523 `postAtTime()` is more accurate over long durations than `postDelayed()` on a fixed interval.

Comment: You may want `postDelayed()`. As I said, it depends on exactly how you want it to operate but the edit I just posted will give you different options so you can see what best suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the Looper class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

A good tutorial for using this, can be found here: http://pierrchen.blogspot.dk/2011/10/thread-looper-and-handler.html

Comment: I didn't get the down vote too. It seems like a correct answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a Handler with timer. But make sure that you must not kill or terminate the runner when living one or other activities

e.g.:

```
   private void timer() {
      mRunnable = new HandlerManger();
      mHandler = new Handler();
      mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000*10);
   }
```

The runnable

```
 private class HandlerManger implements Runnable {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        // your business logic method here;
      }
   }
```

Activity

```
 private Handler mHandler;
   private Runnable mRunnable;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.act...);
      timer();
   }
```

Comment: This will only run once after 10 seconds, if you make it run once a second I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: @Sam I am not agreed with. So far you don't call mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable); You the thread is still running every then 10s if you don't believe me just copy & paste my code and try it by yourselves

Comment: [`postDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) only runs once, how will this "update it's text with random numbers continuously"?

Comment: @Sam he just need to put here public void run() { // your business logic method here;}

Answer (score 0):

This example approach with self-restarting `CountDownTimer` would do. Though this might be not the best approach, it will work

```
     public class CountDown extends Activity {

      TextView tv; 

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       tv = new TextView(this);
       this.setContentView(tv);

      //5000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
      //1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
      MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);

      counter.start();

         }

         public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

      public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
         super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
         }

          @Override
         public void onFinish() {
         this.start();
         }

       @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       tv.setText("your values here");

      }

     }
    }
```